# flutter animation acceleration or speed change

Tags: flutter, animation, flutter-animation

how can we change the acceleration of the animation in duration or make some stops in it's duration?
for example scale a widget to 2x in 3 second than stop for a second than scale it for another 2x in 3 seconds.

```
AnimationController_anim1 = AnimationController(
  vsync: this,
  duration: Duration(milliseconds: 3000),
);
ScaleTransition(
                scale: Tween(begin: 1.0, end: 2).animate(_anim1),
                child: ClipRect(
                  clipBehavior: Clip.hardEdge,
                  child: OverflowBox(
                    maxHeight: 70,
                    maxWidth: 70,
                    child: Center(
                      child: Container(
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          color: Colors.white38,
                          shape: BoxShape.circle,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              )
```

Comment: check `TweenSequence` class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as I searched around, I found the solution in two different ways, one is what Amir Hossein Mirzaei mentioned, which use Curve class, it is very powerful and flexible but it is a bit complicated and hard solution (beside being so powerful), but the second way is more handy which handled by TweenSequence as bellow :
1 - make an animation controller 2- make TweenSequence and add TweenSequenceItem for each step of animation 3- set it to widget

```
AnimationController _anim1 = AnimationController(
  vsync: this,
  duration: Duration(milliseconds: 8500),
  //reverseDuration: Duration(milliseconds: 1000),
)..repeat(reverse: true);


Animation<double> _animation1 = TweenSequence(
  <TweenSequenceItem<double>>[
    TweenSequenceItem<double>(
      tween: Tween<double>(begin: 1.0, end: 1.5),
      weight: 23.5,
    ),
    TweenSequenceItem<double>(
      tween: ConstantTween<double>(1.5),
      weight: 6.0,
    ),
    TweenSequenceItem<double>(
      tween: Tween<double>(begin: 1.5, end: 2.0),
      weight: 23.5,
    ),
    TweenSequenceItem<double>(
      tween: ConstantTween<double>(2.0),
      weight: 47.0,
    ),
  ],
).animate(_anim1);


ScaleTransition(
scale: _animation1,
child: ClipRect(
  clipBehavior: Clip.hardEdge,
  child: OverflowBox(
    maxHeight: 70,
    maxWidth: 70,
    child: Center(
      child: Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: Colors.white38,
          shape: BoxShape.circle,
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ),
),
)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use Curve class which provides a way to map the unit interval of animation to the desired unit interval that your want
for example, curves should implement a transform function whic are mapper that receives a time value in a range of 0,1 which indicates animations current time progress and you can return a value to indicate what should be the new progress of the animation for example you can say if time is greater than 0 then return time*2 which speeds up your animation as 2x also note that you should are allowed to return value in the range of 0 to 1 so in this example, your should bound the time*2 to be at most 1

Here is link to Curve class documentation :
https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/animation/Curve-class.html

also, there are a few ready to use curves in the Curves class that you can already use or look to the implementation of those to inspire :
https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/animation/Curves-class.html

Comment: thank you for nice explanation, it was helpful. but I can't accept it as the complete answer, because I find a more simple way with "TweenSequence" to achieve this, which I 'll post the code as an answer.